# Apache Rewrite Rules for specific cases

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file and a couple of redirect rule.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/migrations/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^blog/digital/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
```

Basically, all my blog urls have been removed but i found redirects rule for every single blog url to redirect to main page. But i want this to be in one rule, something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/{anyUrl}/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
```

Also i have strange redirects, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^2/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^3/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^4/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^5/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^6/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
```

And i want them to be one rule, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^{[2-6]}/?$ / [R=301,L,NE]
```

Can anyone help with those rule, i am not really good at regexps.

//Edited

Also i have a rule that redirects urls with query strings:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

But this rule removes all query strings. How can i exclude from the rule specific query strings that starts with `utm_`?

And how can i get the domain name? I have my website on two different domains. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/? https://{domain}/somewhere
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine all those rules into one rule using regex alternation:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(blog/|[2-6]/?$) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

This pattern `^(blog/|[2-6]/?$)` will match start position and then either `blog/` or `[2-6]` followed by optional `/` and end position.

---

For the other query string rule you can use:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)utm_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L,NE]
```

---

```
RewriteRule ^posts/? https://{domain}/somewhere
```

You don't need to use `https://%{HTTP_HOST}` here in redirect rules to make it same domain as in the request, so make it:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/? https://%{HTTP_HOST}/somewhere [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Could you please help me with another rules. I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, but i exactly needed the domain there, this is experimental.

Comment: First of all this is not a fair practice to keep adding requirements in the same question after you get original problem solved. This forum encourages one post for one problem. Secondly I don't understand what you mean by ` but i exactly needed the domain there`

Comment: I'am sorry for this, but if i didnt get the answer for the first question, i wouldn't even ask the second. What about domain. Me all redirects rules are working strange -> from https -> http -> https. The problem is not in my redirects (i removed them completely), problem is no on the server (devops tries everything), but i want to make experiment, and to redirect to the path including https directly.
so basically i want - ^blog/ -> https://{domain}/posts/. And this is why i want to know the domain, because i have a dev server and a prod server (different domains). Sorry, and thank you.

Comment: [This was your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72446721/1) and it didn't have any requirement for domain. However I will make one more attempt to address this domain thing in my answer as per my understanding. If this don't work please open a new question for domain requirement.